# Separate form parameters with separate hash in rails while click submit button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Iam having the below form in view.

```
<%= form_for (@response)  do |f| %>
<% @questions.each do |pgquestion| %>
    <% if pgquestion.group_id == 0 %>
        <%= label :pgquest,pgquestion.description %><br><br><br>
    <% else %>
    <%= label :pgquest,pgquestion.description %> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

        <% (1..pgquestion.question_value.to_i).each do |i| %>
                <%= radio_button_tag pgquestion.quest_id,i  %>
        <% end %>
        <br><br>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
<%= f.submit 'Prev' %>
<%= f.submit 'Next' %>
<% end %>
```

i got below parameters in from submit.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"v0KJr6hNEOFpbkRJmnOZkWXpGrJCO2pxb/AgUCOUR1kgujXvOArhnmgVmLkuhPYKkLGuS9vRnlsc1SchcgMVzQ==", "11"=>"1", "12"=>"5", "13"=>"7", "14"=>"8", "commit"=>"Next"}
```

and i need like below

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"v0KJr6hNEOFpbkRJmnOZkWXpGrJCO2pxb/AgUCOUR1kgujXvOArhnmgVmLkuhPYKkLGuS9vRnlsc1SchcgMVzQ==",ans_value=["11"=>"1", "12"=>"5", "13"=>"7", "14"=>"8"]", "commit"=>"Next"}
```

please any one help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax

```
<% (1..pgquestion.question_value.to_i).each do |i| %>
  <%= radio_button_tag "ans_value[#{ pgquestion.quest_id }]", i %>
<% end %>
```

should generate the following params

```
ans_value => { "11"=>"1", "12"=>"5", "13"=>"7", "14"=>"8" }
```

I hope that is what you were after.

Comment: above form i added one textarea is it possible to add in this params  ans_value => { "11"=>"1", "12"=>"5", "13"=>"7", "14"=>"8" }

Comment: Yes, should work using the same syntax for the textarea's name

Comment: <%= text_area("ans_value[#{pgquestion.quest_id }]","") %>
i tried like above
ans_value"=>{"11"=>"1", "12"=>"2", "13"=>"3", "14"=>"4", "21"=>["Test Comments"]}
i got the above parameters  i have to remove [] in "21"=>["Test Comments"]

Comment: I think you should use `text_area_tag` instead of `text_area`. Should work fine then.

Comment: Please look at this u have any idea ?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28214180/rails-same-page-with-url-paramaters-only-change